# Removing duplicates column by column in bulk

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2007

I know how to remove duplicates from a single column using Remove Duplicates on the Data tab. However I have 830 columns for which a manual process (select each column in turn and click Remove Duplicates) would be very tedious.

Please, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're willing to use VBA, this would be a simple macro with a for-loop...

Comment: @whoever voted to close this, can you explain? This sounds like a fine question for this site.

Comment: It is an old post, but can anyone provide VBA solution?